# What is the right usage in Fisher test in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, p-value, fishers-exact-test

So I have data in form (in real data I have more rows, of course so this is just a sample)

```
>df <- structure(list(cake.eated = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), is.it.weekend = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)), 
+ .Names = c("is.cake.eated","is.it.weekend"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
>df

 is.cake.eated is.it.weekend
         1             1
         0             1
         0             1
         1             0
         1             1
         1             0
```

and I woulf like to perfotm Fisher's test to it. In contigency-table form my data looks like

```
>c = matrix(c(2205,2605,1442,1042), ncol=2)
>rownames(c) <- c("cake.eated", "cake.not.eated")
>colnames(c) <- c("not.weekend", "weekend")
>c

                  not.weekend  weekend
 cake.eated            2205    1442
 cake.not.eated        2605    1042
```

So my question is, which one of these is the right way to use Fisher's test in R;

```
> fisher.test(c)

      Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  c
p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
0.5539554 0.6753183
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
0.6117068
```

OR

```
>fisher.test(df$is.cake.eated, df$is.it.weekend)
      Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  df$is.cake.eated and df$is.it.weekend
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
0.8607512 1.1611740
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
     1
```

Is Fisher test even okay to use in this case an this kind of data or is some else like chi-squared better? Why are the results from fisher tests so different and what am I doing wrong?

```
> chisq.test(df$is.cake.eated, df$is.it.weekend)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  df$is.cake.eated and df$is.it.weekend
X-squared = 1.781e-06, df = 1, p-value = 0.9989
```

Also, by Barnard test my results look like

```
> barnard.test(2205, 1442, 2605, 1042, dp=0.01)

       Barnard's Unconditional Test

       Treatment I Treatment II
Outcome I         2205         1442
Outcome II        2605         1042

Null hypothesis: Treatments have no effect on the outcomes
Score statistic = 9.88313
Nuisance parameter = 0.03 (One sided), 0.97 (Two sided)
P-value = 7.65658e-22 (One sided), 7.65658e-22 (Two sided)
```

Comment: Where does the `rain.zeros` data come from (where you run `fisher.test(df$is.cake.eated, df$is.it.weekend)` the output data does not match the input.)

Comment: sorry, I copied wrong stuff from my console. Should be okay now

Comment: Thanks. Will try to replicate it and update my answer. Is that the output you get from running it on your real data?

Comment: Yes these were the results from my real data. I will also check this now again couple of times if I haven't noticed something relevant

Comment: And is the table c the real data? An odds ratio of 1 means the outcome is the same in the two groups so I suspect something has gone wrong with the data.

Comment: I found the problem.. I had the contigency table totally wrong.. heh, this is kind of embarrassing =/. But yeh, the real one looks like `contig = matrix(c(412,1033,630,1575), ncol=2)´  But thanks anyway, you made me to question myself and that solved the problem =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fisher.test**

With `fisher.test` you can run it either on a table, as in your example `fisher.test(c)` or you can run it on two vectors, as in your second example. It looks like the output you have provided from `fisher.test(df$is.cake.eated, df$is.it.weekend)` does not match the input. They should correspond if the correct data are used:

```
df <- structure(list(cake.eated = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), is.it.weekend = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)),
                .Names = c("is.cake.eated","is.it.weekend"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")


fisher.test(df$is.cake.eated, df$is.it.weekend)
```

Gives

```
    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  table(df)
p-value = 0.4667
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.00000 11.81149
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
         0
```

And `fisher.test(table(df))` gives

```
    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  table(df)
p-value = 0.4667
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.00000 11.81149
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
         0
```

**Chi-squared test**

The chi-squared test and Fisher's exact test are used to do similar things: test the association between two categorical variable. However, they go about it in different ways. You can find details in standard statistics text books, but basically the chi-squared test approximates the p value (it is said to be 'asymptotic') whereas the *exact* test gives an *exact* p value. For this reason I tend to always use Fisher's exact but you could use chi-squared here.

The rule of thumb about using chi-squared is that no cell in the table should have an expected cell count of less than 1, and no more than 20% of the cells should have an expected count of less than 5. You can access the expected cell counts in R:

`chisq.test(c)$exp`

In your example, this is satisfied and the chi-squared approximation is valid:

```
chisq.test(c)$exp
               not.weekend weekend
cake.eated            2405    1242
cake.not.eated        2405    1242

chisq.test(c)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  c
X-squared = 97.189, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
```